# Adding images and text from database to list in Android

Tags: android, android-activity, view, listactivity

I am facing some problem in understanding the terminologies and their uses.

I would like to know what *adapter* means, what is the use of it and where will it be used? Please provide a simple explanation.

Also, I would like to load images plus text over listview, how do I achieve that? Imagine I have a huge set of elements present in a database, how do I load them faster over List?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An [Adapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html) object acts as a bridge between an [AdapterView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html) and the underlying data for that view. The `Adapter` provides access to the data items. The `Adapter` is also responsible for making a View for each item in the data set.

An `AdapterView` is a view whose children are determined by an `Adapter`.

Some examples of AdapterViews are `ListView`, `GridView`, `Spinner` and `Gallery`.

[Binding to Data with AdapterView](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/binding.html)

For different types of Adapters look at the blog ertry *[Android Adapters: an introduction](http://androidforbeginners.blogspot.in/2010/01/android-adapters-introduction.html)*

Also highly recommended is [the Google I/O presentation given by Romain Guy](http://developer.android.com/videos/index.html#v=N6YdwzAvwOA).

Comment: For loading lots of images in list [Android - How do I do a lazy load of images in ListView](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/541966/android-how-do-i-do-a-lazy-load-of-images-in-listview)